# CDI event triggered from MDB to update JSF page

Tags: jsf, jms, cdi

Is it possible to fire a CDI event from an MDB? This MDB is monitoring a JMS queue and then a JSF page needs to be updated.

The issue that I'm experiencing is the JSF bean has a scope (was session, but trying request) and the MDB has no scope. The JSF bean contains the controller code (updating the page) and the @Observes annotation on a method parameter. Because the MDB is not in a 'context' and has no scope, the CDI event is never triggered on the JSF Bean.

How is it even possible then to update a JSF page based on a JMS (with MDB) event?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm pretty sure of my what I'm claiming here but not 100%.

You can't do it with just MDB and CDI events. Typically a CDI event reuses the request thread and executes events synchronously after your method was invoked. That means that it's a potential bottleneck even if it worked. The second part is that it will find observers based on the request that spawned it and not find other "users" or whatever.

You can bridge this in several different ways and with several technologies but WebSockets / the Atmosphere framework is usually a solid way to get the message out there. Note that Primefaces Push exists and is based on Atmosphere.

I had a project recently (small) where I needed a plain tomcat and I could not use WebSockets so I brewed up a solution using CDI events.

It works like this:

1. Instead of using `event.fire(new myEvent())` I went for something more transparent, ie I wanted it to show clearly that this event will be broadcasted to all sessions. So instead I created what I called `SessionEventDelegator`. It has a method called `putEvent(Object object)` (also other methods when you need Qualifiers). When you want to send events to all sessions you simply inject that and "put" your event. Maybe I should call it load since it will get fired later ;p
2. Later A JSF `PhaseListener` calls `getEvents()` and get all new events since the last time it checked. A timestamp functionality is in place so that you only get new events.
3. Now simply iterate over found events and use BeanManager.fire to get them out.
4. Since the `PhaseListener` will only trigger when the user makes a new request I use `p:poll` from primefaces ensuring that it polls for new events every third second.
5. A cleanup algorithm makes sure that events that everyone got is removed from the queue in SessionEventDelegator.

if you want the code let me know. To lazy to paste it if it doesn't sound right to you.

Comment: Hi, I realise this an older thread but I have to do something similar and would be interested in seeing the code, if you don't mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case that CDI events won't work (I am not convinced about that because spec says that non-contextual objects can't observe events, there is nothing about firing them) but simplest workaround seems to use interceptor. MDBs can have interceptors so just intercept `onMessage` method and fire event from the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fire CDI events from MDBs.  The problem is that they're only going to be observed at the application level.  If you're using push technology (e.g. Websockets) you can have this `ApplicationScoped` object receive the event, and then push to the appropriate client based on session id in websockets.

Answer (score 0):

In RichFaces library there's `a4j:push` component that does exactly what you need. Check out the [RichFaces Push section](http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/richfaces_4_2.html)